# Screen artifacts after the first boot

Tags: xorg, xrandr, monitors

During the first boot the monitor whistles for a while, and the mouse pointer has a strange artifact:

[image]
[image]

But after "Log out" / "Log in" - everything is fine. Any ideas what it can be and how to resolve?

- KDE Neon 5.11.3 (Ubuntu 16)
- MSI GE72 6QF (GeForce GTX 970M)

Additional error from /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
randr: falling back to unsynchronized pixmap sharing
```

`xrandr --verbose` output:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
    eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1f2) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
        Identifier: 0x1ed
        Timestamp:  48464
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff0030e4690400000000
                00180104952615780a0bb5a35955a027
                0c505400000001010101010101010101
                010101010101e835809670381f403020
                35007ed71000001a0000000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000fe004c
                4720446973706c61790a2020000000fe
                004c503137335746342d535046310022
        PRIME Synchronization: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
        scaling mode: Full aspect 
                supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x1f2) 138.000MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2070 skew    0 clock  66.67KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.01Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1f3) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1f4) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz                               
  1680x1050 (0x1f5) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync                                                                 
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz                              
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz                               
  1600x1024 (0x1f6) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync                                                                 
        h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz                              
        v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz                               
  1400x1050 (0x1f7) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync                                                                 
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz                              
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz                               
  1280x1024 (0x1f8) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync                                                                 
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz                              
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz                               
  1440x900 (0x1f9) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync                                                                  
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz                              
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz                               
  1280x960 (0x1fa) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync                                                                  
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz                              
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1360x768 (0x1fb) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x1fc) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1152x864 (0x1fd) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1fe) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x1ff) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x200) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x201) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x202) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  960x600 (0x203) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x204) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  800x600 (0x205) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x206) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x207) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x208) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x209) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  800x512 (0x20a) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
  700x525 (0x20b) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  640x512 (0x20c) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  720x450 (0x20d) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  640x480 (0x20e) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x20f) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  680x384 (0x210) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  680x384 (0x211) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  576x432 (0x212) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
  512x384 (0x213) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  400x300 (0x214) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x215) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  320x240 (0x216) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x1ee
        Timestamp:  48464
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:     HDMI-1-1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        PRIME Synchronization: 1 
                supported: 0, 1
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x1ef
        Timestamp:  48464
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:     DP-1-1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        PRIME Synchronization: 1 
                supported: 0, 1
        aspect ratio: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x1f0
        Timestamp:  48464
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTCs:      0 1 2
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        PRIME Synchronization: 1 
                supported: 0, 1
        aspect ratio: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
```

After Log out/in was changed to:

```
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x47) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
```

Comment: `xrandr --verbose` please.

Comment: @Bahamut, added

Comment: I can not try the  solution, only one card.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1674304   bugreport and maybe helpfull https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449&p=13663158&viewfull=1#post13663158

Comment: It seems to be outdated :( not workable for me... actual driver version `nvidia_384_drm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has appeared recently.

Enable repository with Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Install `Additional Drivers` tool via `Software Center`

Update it to the latest version (in my case it was: `390.48`)